# Expected value in term of characteristic function

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a random variable. It is known that for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+,$ of class $C^1,$ increasing, $f(0)=0,$
$$E[f(|X|)]=\int_0^{+\infty}f'(x)P(|X|>x)dx=\int_0^{+\infty}f'(x)(1-F_{|X|}(x))dx \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$ In particular, if $X \in L^1,$ then $E[X]=\int_0^{+\infty}(1-F_X(x)-F_X(-x))dx.$

Also $E[|X|]=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{]0;+\infty[}\frac{1-\Re(\varphi_X(x))}{x^2}dx.$

In $(1), E[f(X)]$ is expressed in term of the distribution function $F_{|X|},$ is there an expression for $E[f(X)]$ in term of $\varphi_X$ ? In particular, if $X \in L^1,$ how can we write $E[X]$ in term of $\varphi_X$? To do so, is it possible to find $\varphi_{X^+}$ and $\varphi_{X^-}$ in term $\varphi_X$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, let $\varphi = \varphi_X$ for convenience, and then consider

$$ \begin{align}
\varphi' (0)  & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \varphi(h) - \varphi(0) }{h} \\
& = \lim_{h \to 0} \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{e^{ihx} -1}{h} dP(x) \\
& = \int_\mathbb{R} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{ihx} -1}{h} dP(x) \\
& = \int_\mathbb{R} ix dP(x) \\
& = i E(X)
\end{align} $$

so $E(X) = -i\varphi'(0)$. You need $|X|$ to be integrable to move the limit inside the integral using dominated convergence. I'm not sure what is true in general.

Whatever $f$ is, there's some new distribution $P_f$ and you have $-i \varphi_{f(X)}'(0) = E(f(X))$, with the same $L^1$ caveat.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

(Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment.)

Sometimes you can write $$\mathrm E[f(X)] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(t) \varphi_X(t) dt,$$ where $f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$, thanks to Parseval's identity. Even more often, you can write it in the distributional sense: $$\mathrm E[f(X)] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \langle \hat f , \varphi_X\rangle.$$ For example, the Fourier transform of $x^2$ is $-2\pi\delta''_0(t)$, so $$\mathrm E[X^2] = -\langle \delta_0'',\varphi_X\rangle = -\varphi''_X (0),$$ which we know does hold provided that $\mathrm E[X^2]<\infty$.

Comment: Well, looking for an integral expression (without using the derivative), $E[X]$ in term of distribution function is obtain by taking $X^+, X^-$ and finding their distribution function in term of $F_X.$ So for characteristic function, $X \in L^1$ if and only if $\int_{0}^{+\infty}(\frac{1-\Re (\varphi_{X^+}(x))}{x^2}+\frac{1-\Re(\varphi_{X^-}(x))}{x^2})dx<+\infty,$ and in this case $E[X]=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\Re(\varphi_{X^-}(x)-\varphi_{X^+}(x))}{x^2}dx,$ do not know if we can do more

Comment: It seems that we can express the characteristic function of $X^+$ in term of $\varphi_X,$ but it's complicated (it was asked once on stack exchange)

Comment: @Kurt.W.X. You don't need the characteristic functions of $X_+$ and $X_-$ to compute $\mathrm E [X] $ (see another answer).

Comment: you mean the derivative?

Comment: Trying to find $E[X]$ without a derivative $(E[|X|])=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1-\Re(\varphi_X(x))}{x^2},$ here we integrated characteristic function)